# Como configurar um certificado para fazer uma conexão com WebSockets do JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, certificado-digital, websocket

Como configurar um certificado para fazer uma conexão com WebSockets do JavaScript, utilizando como servidor o SuperWebSocket do c#?

Preciso criar uma conexão websocket em uma página https, a única forma é utilizando "wss", que possui o protrocolo SSL, porém eu não sei como utilizar corretamente esse tipo de conexão.

```
        public static void startServer()
        {

            ServerConfig config = new ServerConfig()
            {
                Name = "SuperWebSocket",
                Ip = "Any",
                Port = 8088,
                Mode = SocketMode.Tcp,
                Security = "tls"
            };

            CertificateConfig certificate = new CertificateConfig()
            {
                FilePath = @"C:/meucaminho",
                Password = "123"
            };
```

Comment: Qual lib é usada? Esta https://github.com/kerryjiang/SuperWebSocket?

Comment: Exatamente esta.

Comment: Há a indicação de que o projeto foi terminado, juntando-se ao `SuperSocket`. Há a possibilidade de usar este outro projeto?

Comment: SuperWebSocket is being merged into SuperSocket as an additional module SuperSocket.WebSocket. You can use SuperSocket.WebSocket in the same way with SuperWebSocket but with a different namespace. https://github.com/kerryjiang/SuperWebSocket

Comment: @tvdias usar SuperSocket no meu projeto? sim, vou implementar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O exemplo original (mais abaixo) usa a versão mais recente do `SuperSocket`, ainda em versão beta e somente para .net core (conforme indicado no readme do repositório).
Entretanto, na documentação do projeto consta instruções de como fazer o mesmo na versão 1.6: http://docs.supersocket.net/v1-6/en-US/Enable-TLS-SSL-trasnferring-layer-encryption-in-SuperSocket

---

**(ORIGINAL)**

Conforme exemplo no projeto `SuperSocket` (substituto do `SuperWebSocket`), segue como pode ser feito, usando a versão para .net core (master branch).

```cs
var host = WebSocketHostBuilder.Create()
    .ConfigureWebSocketMessageHandler(async (session, message) =>
    {
        // echo message back to the client
        await session.SendAsync(message.Message);
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((hostCtx, loggingBuilder) =>
    {
        // register your logging library here
        loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
    }).Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

Para o código acima funcionar é necessário o seguinte arquivo de configuração `appsettings.json`

```js
{
    "serverOptions": {
        "name": "TestWebSocketServer",
        "listeners": [
            {
                "ip": "Any",
                "port": 4040
            },
            {
                "ip": "Any",
                "port": 4041,
                "security": "Tls12",
                "certificateOptions" : {
                    "filePath": "certificado.pfx",
                    "password": "SENHA DO CERtIFICADO"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Exemplo disponível em https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kerryjiang/SuperSocket/master/samples/WebSocketServer/Program.cs